# Mapping between Spark configurations and parameters

Tags: apache-spark

When I launch spark in command line, I found parameter `num-executors` acts similar as `spark.executor.instances` in the configuration file. Are they actually the same? If so, where can I find a full mapping between all such pairs of same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/configuration.html)

> The Spark shell and spark-submit tool support two ways to load
>   configurations dynamically. The first are command line options, such
>   as --master, as shown above. spark-submit can accept any Spark
>   property using the --conf flag, but uses special flags for properties
>   that play a part in launching the Spark application. Running
>   ./bin/spark-submit --help will show the entire list of these options.

So, there are way fewer command line options such as `--executor-cores` than there is spark options such as `spark.executor.cores`, and like documentation says, you get those `--` options by running `./bin/spark-submit --help`. Do run this - it will tell you that not all CL options are usable in every situation (something that confused me a lot). You can set any property that does not have a special command line option like so: `--conf spark.executor.cores=16`.

[Here is an incomplete table](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties) - you must read through the comments to find the appropriate parameters.